# Deleting private/ root/ trash(14gb)

Tags: finder, trash, root

M1 MacBook on Monterey 12.4. I have a problem that there is a folder in private/ root that takes up 13 gb of storage which i cannot delete through finder.

This folder only contains of long forgotten Visualstudio Packages, Teams packages (I dont use teams anymore) and a bunch of stuff that I AM SURE that are safe to delete. I deleted them some time ago and they are not gone yet.
**[image: strong text]**

**how can i delete this stuff?**

Comment: How did it get there? When you say "I deleted them", what did you do? Have you restarted in Safe Boot mode, and then done a normal restart?

Comment: Im using DiskInventoryX to visualise all the data on my drive. What i mean by "I deleted them" is that couple of months ago i deleted these folders because i didnt have any more use for them and as far as i remember i did not delete them in any _weird_ way.

Comment: Did you just normally download these installers? I'm trying to understand how they got where they are now. Are/were you running as the root user?

Comment: I think that these files somehow got there when i updated/ installed visual studio for the mac. 95% of all the files you can see are somehow Visual studio related. Except Teams and Croctile 3d for whatever reason. I installed visual studio as the admin user (so normally), just like teams and Croctile 3d. And when i didnt need the latter two i just deleted the applications. I dont understand how they got there at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete them as the root user with some commands like:

```
sudo su root
cd /private/var/root/Trash
ls -la
rm -Ri *
```

`rm -R *` **will be a disaster if you are not in the right place** - be careful. The `ls -la` is intended to confirm that you are in the right place. The `i` in the `rm` is optional and will ask you to confirm each file - leave it out once you gain confidence! You would be safer to use `rm -Ri Xamarin`, etc. doing each folder individually.

Read `man rm` if you are not familiar with the `rm` command.

Of course, deleting anything as the root user can be risky (your risk). But I can't see any obvious reason not to delete the contents of your root's trash.

Comment: surely better to `sudo rm -Ri /private/var/root/Trash/*` rather thna going into root

Comment: Yeah i guess a combination of both would be perfect, so i can make sure that the contents of the directory is correct.

Comment: While it worked, i don't recommend using -i unless you are not sure what you are deleting. In this case i knew it so i didn't have to use it.

Comment: @mmmmmm You are probably right.  Just seemed easier to go step by step the way I suggested - but maybe not.

Comment: @Rarowcun I was being, perhaps, being over cautious by suggesting the -i.